# how to add the trigger s3 bucket to lambda function dynamically(python boto3 API)

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

how to add trigger s3 bucket to lambda function with boto3, then I want attach that lambda function to dynamically created s3 buckets using programmatically(boto3)

Comment: also I want add suffix to that bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps I followed
1) connected to aws lambda with boto3 used add_permission API
2)also applyed get_policy
3)connected to S3 with boto resource to  configuring BucketNotification API,put LambdaFunctionConfigurations

Comment: I'm working on the same topic, can you share a code snippet ? Willbe very useful.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
client = boto3.client(
                    's3',
                    aws_access_key_id=AWSAccessKeyID,
                    aws_secret_access_key=AWSSecretAccessKey)

response = client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
Bucket=bucketName,
NotificationConfiguration= {'LambdaFunctionConfigurations':[{'LambdaFunctionArn': '<MyLambdaFunctionARN>', 'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*']}]})
```

Comment: you're the bext

Answer (score 3):

The complete answer for this question with the source code is:

Functions to initiate at lambda client:

```
response1 = lambda1.add_permission(FunctionName='put*your*lambda*arn*here',
                               StatementId='response2-id-2',
                               Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
                               Principal='s3.amazonaws.com',
                               SourceArn='put*your*s3*bucket*arn*here'
                              )
response2 = lambda1.get_policy(FunctionName='put*your*lambda*arn*here')
```

Function to initiate at the s3 bucket:

```
response3 = s3.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
                            Bucket='put*your*bucket-name*here',
                            NotificationConfiguration= {'LambdaFunctionConfigurations':[{'LambdaFunctionArn': 'put*your*lambda*arn*here', 'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*']}]})
```

Your s3 trigger will be attached to you lambda.